# UCC cert for single IIS7.5 site with multiple domains forwarded via rewrites

Tags: url-rewriting, iis7, ucc-certificate

We have a site that has 80-some-odd aliases. In other words, each host name's DNS entry points to the same IP address and port number, and when they reach our IIS7.5 server they are forwarded to the sole site that has been set up. (It's a CMS platform that hosts many client sites.)

We'd like to purchase a multiple-domain certificate (UCC) and have it work for all of the rewritten domains simply by installing it for the sole IIS site that everything is forwarded to.

Is this possible? Or will we need to set up unique sites in IIS for every host name?